# How can I find a mode and median of a column with numbers in Metabase?(Metabase is a BI Tool)

Tags: statistics, median, mode, metabase

How can I find a mode and median of a column with numbers in Metabase? (Metabase is a BI Tool)

Comment: Which data source are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the datasource, you can use the [native query mode](https://www.metabase.com/docs/latest/users-guide/writing-sql) to do this.

Other than that metabase currently does not offer mode and median for summary.